# Calculate total calls made to a method without using static

Tags: java, file, static, io

UPDATE:: OK i am putting the original problem statement here

Given the Main class create a method createPerson and call it in any other method more than once, then on the basis of the number of times the createPerson has been executed you have to initialize the objects and input names of students and output the names.

once i come to know how many objects i have to create its quite trivial to program the later part

for the prior problem of finding the number of objects to be created i have chosen the way of file handling as i come from a C, C++ background where file handling is comparatively simple.

now how should i modify the program such that i write an integer in the file, and later when i will read the file i will get the number of objects

this example forbids the use of static variable, it is a sort of brain teaser
so do **Not** use static

this is my Main.java file

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        int i;
        Student[] totalStudents = new Student[10];
         Student.create3Persons();
          Student.create2Persons();
    }

}
```

and this is my Student.java file

```
import java.io.*;
public class Student {


    private static void createPerson() throws IOException{
        int number=0;
        File file = new   File("arg.txt", null);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
        while(dis.readInt()!= -1)
        {
            number++;
            dos.writeInt(1);
        }
    }

     static void create2Persons() throws IOException{
        Student.createPerson();
        Student.createPerson();
    }

    static void create3Persons() throws IOException{
        Student.createPerson();
        Student.createPerson();
        Student.createPerson();
    }
}
```

How should i modify this program so that i calculate how many times has been the function createPerson being called??

Comment: Seems like a homework you have to do, is that correct?

Comment: not _ technically_ a homework
my Prof asked in the class "lets see if you can solve this"

Comment: I added the homework tag in this case, since the community will not want to give you the exact answer, but rather help you find it with well guided advices.

Comment: thank you, actually i didn't knew there was a tag named "homework" :)
ok don't give exact answer just hint me whats wrong!!

Comment: @Laf i found out the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the Solution
instead of file handling i am doing this

```
 static int createPerson(int c){
        return (++c);
    }

     static int create2Persons(int c) {

    return Student.createPerson(Student.createPerson(c));
    }

    static int create3Persons(int c) {

        return Student.createPerson(Student.createPerson(Student.createPerson(c)));


    }




        public static int create5Persons(int i) {
   return Student.createPerson(Student.createPerson(Student.createPerson(Student.createPerson(Student.createPerson(i)))));
        }
```

and in the main method i have initialised an integer and i do this

```
 c += Student.create2Persons(i)-1;
          c += Student.create3Persons(i)-1;
          c += Student.create5Persons(i)-1;
          System.out.println(c+"c is");
```

this saves use of files

how to tag the thread as answered?

Comment: i know its a bit too late but: all those nested calls, are they really necessary ? maybe you could specify the person number in a dynamic kind of way ... imagine you need a create60Persons() method

Comment: actually the question above which i asked was an assignment by my professor, he wanted to make us think how can we calculate number of objects without using static variables, and the nested calls was in the problem statement

Comment: and sir had asked us to use linked list, but i programmed it without the use of linked list

Answer (score 7):

If you want to calculate how many times a static method has been called, you *have* to use a static variable - it's genuinely global state. EDIT: Yes, you *can* use the file system as another repository for global state, but I'd personally say that's generally a bad idea - particularly if it's *just* to get round a requirement in an academic question.

I guess there are some exceptions to this - if the static method is provably only called from one class, and that class is a singleton, then there could be an instance method in that singleton... but that's pretty much a corner case. In your case, `create3Persons` and `create2Persons` are both accessible from anywhere in the package, and they *aren't* instance methods in a singleton, so therefore there's no single context in which to keep the call count *except* a static variable.

Perhaps if you could explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve, we could help you more...

EDIT: Yes, if you can rely on *cooperative* callers - and you can change the method signatures - then you could keep (say) an `AtomicInteger`, and make sure you always pass a reference to the same object into the `createStudent` method. Again, we'd really need to know what the rules of the question are...

Comment: Actually in the problem statement it is specified don't use static variable and calculate the number of times the createPerson() was executed on that basis i have to initialize an array of class Student and then input that many names and output them

Comment: @lucifer: I've explained in my answer how you *can't* automatically count the number of calls to the static method without using a static variable *somewhere*. (I suppose you can use the file system as your global state, but it's pretty similar in many ways.) It's really unclear what the purpose of this is. Perhaps if you could give more context...

Comment: Oh sorry
i am doing it by using file handling
in the createfunction() defination i am writing to a file then i will read the file and simply count the no of variables in the File!
thus no need for static variable

Comment: @lucifer: That feels like a *really* smelly way of avoiding a static variable. Are you sure that's in the spirit of the question?

Comment: Sorry sir it is the question do it Without using Static variable i am not doing anything illegal in it actually Our sir gave us this question today and i have been breaking my head since 8pm today on file handling in Java( i am a newbie in java)
atlast i wrote the above program but its giving wrong output

Comment: @lucifer: But I strongly suspect you *aren't* meant to use the file system, unless this is a pretty bizarre problem. Can you post the *full text* of the problem in the question? A bit more context would help, too...

Comment: One could also argue that the name/URI whatever of the File is, well, a static variable.  :-)

Comment: Actually the statement didn't suggest use file system, i am from a C++ background so i thought of file handling as an option

so is there any other way to solve this without using Files or Static variables??

Comment: I think @jambriz and Naveen's solutions may be what the brain teaser wants.  But it doesn't really work in a multithreaded environment.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - I'm not sure how the cooperative callers manage a single AtomicInteger without using a static (or a lot of work???)  Am I missing a simple solution?

Comment: @Jon Skeet did you get my question??

Answer (score 2):

i have to disagree with @Jon Skeet, i dont think you *have* to use a static variable. Why not simply return the number of items created, and keep the total count in a local variable in your main method ? (assuming youre allowed to modifiy method signatures of course, otherwise youre stuck with the global variable solution) you seem to have an unused counter right there already, why not use it?

Comment: Yes, if we can change the signature of `createPerson` (or the methods that call it) that is indeed a valid option. Have added that into my answer. It won't prevent `createPerson` from being called from other code and "losing" that count, of course. It's hard to know what's allowed without seeing the question, unfortunately...

Comment: If `createPerson(int inCount)` is called from multiple threads, what do they pass for inCount?  Hmm, they probably need some global static somewhere...

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
synchronized(this){
   System.setProperty("methodCounter",number++);
}
```

instead of a file based counter.  And in the main method:

```
System.getProperty("methodCounter");
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly when we want to retain value across method, either we go for

- Static variable
- or pass the variable as reference
- or pass the variable and return the updated variable and use it again

  int createPerson(int counter);

Comment: Nice try!  Your first example (passing an Integer) doesn't work because Integer is immutable, (you could pass an int[1] instead which is a kludge).  And your 2nd version works.  Sortof.  It won't work in a multithreaded case.  If two separate threads are calling createPerson they can't possibly keep the count right.

Comment: @user949300: Using a single `AtomicInteger` object would do it, mind you :)

Comment: removed my example for passing by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use AOP (Aspect-Oriented Programming).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a system property to store the quantity of calls...this way you don't have to use the file system or AOP or change method signature.