# Best practices for verifying recursive method calls with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Consider this example class:

```
public class Processor {
  private final Dependency dependency;

  public Processor(Dependency dependency) {
    this.dependency = dependency;
  }

  public void processUsers(List<Integer> userIds, int attempt) {
    if (attempt == 0) {
      //log initial processing
    } else if (attempt > 0 && attempt < 5) {
      //log retry processing
    } else {
      //log processing limit exceeded
      return;
    }
    List<Integer> failedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer userId : userIds) {
      try {
        processUser(userId);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        //logging
        failedIds.add(userId);
      }
    }
    if (failedIds.isEmpty()) {
      //log ok
    } else {
      processUsers(failedIds, attempt + 1);
    }
  }

  public void processUser(Integer userId) throws Exception{
    //dependency can throw exception
    dependency.call();
  }
}
```

I would like to verify that method `processUsers` calls itself when exception is thrown.
Here is my testy test:

```
public class ProcessorTest {
  @Test
  public void processShouldCallItselfWithFailedSublistWhenProcessingFails(){
    Dependency dependency = mock(Dependency.class);
    when(dependency.call()).thenThrow(Exception.class);
    Processor processor = new Processor(dependency);
    processor.processUsers(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3}), 0);
    //need to verify processor will call #processUsers recursively
    //because the dependency thrown Exception, how?
  }
}
```

What are best practices for verifying that method calls itself recursively under certain circumstances?

I'm using TestNG + Mockito and this verbose language called `JAVA`

Comment: Does dependency really not use the userId parameter?

Comment: It does, just an example of actual usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can verify the number of times `dependency.call()` is invoked.  This would tell you that retry worked - just by the number of calls:

```
@Test
public void processShouldCallItselfWithFailedSublistWhenProcessingFails() {
    Dependency dependency = mock(Dependency.class);
    when(dependency.call()).thenReturn(1, 2).thenThrow(Exception.class).
        thenReturn(4);
    Processor processor = new Processor(dependency);
    processor.processUsers(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}), 0);
    verify(dependency, times(4)).call();
}
```

This would tell you that retry eventually failed with too many exceptions:

```
@Test
public void processShouldFailAfterTooManyRetries() {
    Dependency dependency = mock(Dependency.class);
    when(dependency.call()).thenThrow(Exception.class);
    Processor processor = new Processor(dependency);
    final List<Integer> userIds = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});
    final int expectedRetries = 5;
    processor.processUsers(userIds, 0);
    verify(dependency, times(expectedRetries * userIds.size())).call();
}
```

If the call to dependency actually used the userId, then you could actually check that all the expected calls to `dependency.call(int userId)` happened.  This would tell you that it all of them went through given enough retries:

```
@Test
public void processShouldCallItselfWithFailedSublistWhenProcessingFails() {
    Dependency dependency = mock(Dependency.class);
    when(dependency.call(anyInt())).
        thenReturn(1, 2).thenThrow(Exception.class).thenReturn(4);
    Processor processor = new Processor(dependency);
    processor.processUsers(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3}), 0);
    verify(dependency).call(1);
    verify(dependency).call(2);
    verify(dependency, times(2)).call(3);
}

@Test
public void processShouldFailAfterTooManyRetries() {
    Dependency dependency = mock(Dependency.class);
    when(dependency.call(anyInt())).thenThrow(Exception.class);
    Processor processor = new Processor(dependency);
    final List<Integer> userIds = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3});
    final int expectedRetries = 5;
    processor.processUsers(userIds, 0);
    for (Integer userId : userIds) {
        verify(dependency, times(expectedRetries)).call(userId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about best practices but you can achieve same by verifying number of times the method is invoked

```
 int invocationCount = 5; // Or any other desired number
 verify(processor,times(invocationCount)).processUsers();
```

Comment: How can I verify on a regular object, not a mock?

Comment: @ValentinVasilyev http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992456/calculate-total-calls-made-to-a-method-without-using-static

Comment: I ended up using spies for this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and did not find an out-of-the-box solution, so here's something that worked for me: spy a parameter object.

Create a parameter object and modify it so you method uses it as follows:

```
public class Processor {
    private final Dependency dependency;

    public Processor(Dependency dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }

    public void processUsers(ProcessorParameters params) {
        if (params.attempt == 0) {
            //log initial processing
        } else if (params.attempt > 0 && params.attempt < 5) {
            //log retry processing
        } else {
            //log processing limit exceeded
            return;
        }
        List<Integer> failedIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (Integer userId : params.userIds) {
            try {
                processUser(userId);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //logging
                failedIds.add(userId);
            }
        }
        if (failedIds.isEmpty()) {
            //log ok
        } else {
            processUsers(params.userIds(failedIds).next(params.attempt + 1));
        }
    }

    public void processUser(Integer userId) throws Exception{
        //dependency can throw exception
        dependency.call();
    }

    protected static class ProcessorParameters
    {
        private List<Integer> userIds;
        private int attempt = 0;

        public ProcessorParameters userIds(List<Integer> userIds) {
            this.userIds = userIds;
            return this;
        }

        public ProcessorParameters next(int attempt) {
            this.attempt = attempt;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how your test class would look:

```
class ProcessorTest
{
    @Test
    public void processShouldCallItselfWithFailedSublistWhenProcessingFails() throws Exception
    {
        Dependency dependency = mock(Dependency.class);
        doThrow(new Exception()).when(dependency).call();
        Processor processor = new Processor(dependency);

        // Allows you to see what parameters are passed, but this object
        // still serves as the method parameters.
        ProcessorParameters params = spy(new ProcessorParameters());

        processor.processUsers(params.userIds(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3})));

        ArgumentCaptor<Integer> attemptCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Integer.class);
        ArgumentCaptor<List<Integer>> userIdsCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);
        verify(params, times(6)).userIds(userIdsCaptor.capture());
        verify(params, times(5)).next(attemptCaptor.capture());

        // Each entry in here is another recursive call to processUsers
        // You can capture the value of each parameter passed in order.
        userIdsCaptor.getAllValues().forEach(System.out::println);
        attemptCaptor.getAllValues().forEach(System.out::println);

        verify(dependency, times(15)).call();
    }
}
```

While this does not allow you to directly verify that "processUsers" was called in the traditional Mockito sense, it does add a great deal of insight. You can capture parameters to observe the recursion behavior, you can skip ahead/behind, you can view the order that certain user IDs were called, etc. That is, you could have the exception thrown only for certain users and verify follow-on behavior.